# How to fetch profile name from google activity and display in other activity layout

Tags: java, android, api

Hello i am trying to build a app using google sdk, i want to display the profile name in other activity where i have EditText.
For example :- GoogleActivity.java to UserInformation.java

i have successfully created google login so now i want to fetch profile name from GoogleActivity.java and want to display in UserInformation.java
Here is my code for USerInformation.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_signin);
        signInToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_signin);
        setSupportActionBar(signInToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        signInToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_arrow);

        OtpVerify = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.OtpVerification);
        editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);

        signInToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>Sign Up</font>"));
        OtpVerify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                OtpVerification();
            }
        });


    }

    private void OtpVerification() {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View OtpDialongScreen = inflater.inflate(R.layout.otpverification, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setView(OtpDialongScreen);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        final AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
        dialog.show();

    }


}
```

can anyone help me to display the profile name in EditText

Comment: so basically you want to pass the string from GoogleActivity to UserInformation activity right??

Comment: @Firdoesh Khan pass your name through intent.putExtra("name","xyz") and get it in desired activity

Comment: yes @himanshu1496 u are right.. how can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the user iformation from Google API using the following code. Or for more details you can refer :  https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people#before_you_begin

```
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
String personId = acct.getId();
Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
```

Now, the user's name is in the variable personName. After successful login, the application will not enters in login page so its better to save the user information in **SharedPreference**.Create a class **AppUtils**.java

```
public class AppUtils {

private final static String SHARED_PREFS="AppUtils";
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor edit;

public AppUtils(Context context) {
    prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public void setUserName(String name) {

    edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putString("name", name);
    edit.commit();
}

public String getUserName() {
    return prefs.getString("name", "");
}
```

}

So in your **GoogleActivity**.java class after fetching the username set it to a shared preference object by calling the function setUserName().

```
AppUtils utils=new AppUtils(UserInformation.this);
utils.setUserName(personName);
```

And whenever you wants call the function getUserName(). In your case :

```
AppUtils utils=new AppUtils(UserInformation.this);

editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);

editTextUsername.setText(utils.getUserName());
```

Comment: `UserInformation.this` can u guide what is this

Comment: It is the context of that activity. Context  is context of current state of the application/object. It provides services like resolving resources, obtaining access to databases and preferences, and so on. An android app has activities. It’s like a handle to the environment your application is currently running in. The activity object inherits the Context object. For more information refer the link  : http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/what-is-context-in-android/